# Directory not empty in installing OpenCV3 with Python3 bindings on macOS

Tags: macos, python-3.x, opencv

I've been trying to upgrade my OpenCV2 to OpenCV3 on my macOS Sierra 10.12.5, using homebrew and also have its bindings for both Python2 and Python3.

Following the excellent guide at pyimagesearch, I got to run

`brew install opencv3 --with-contrib --with-python3 --HEAD`

(I first uninstalled OpenCV, just for clarity and to avoid any potential conflicts). Now, the guide explains that `--with-contrib` is downloading additional stuff, which is good to have; `--with-python3` is downloading the bindings for Python3 (those for Python2 are automatically there); `--HEAD` is pulling the Github branch version rather than the tagged release, which is a workaround to a problem related to the QKIT Apple library.

My problem is I get a

`Error: Directory not empty - (/usr/local/Cellar/numpy/1.13.1, /usr/local/Cellar/numpy/1.13.1.tmp)`

A `brew doctor` tells me Numpy is not linked but I'm not exactly sure what'd be the best way to proceed here. Wouldn't want to break something.

At this point, I just tested installing just the bindings for Python2, as in

`brew install opencv3 --with-contrib --HEAD`

and this leads me to this other problem:

`Error: No such file or directory - /private/tmp/opencv3-20170714-55298-snr5jb/3rdparty/ippicv/downloader.cmake`,

which is solved with if I instead run

`brew install opencv3 --with-contrib`

This last one works, I got OpenCV3 for Python2. Apparently I don't have the HEAD issue.

Now though, I still want the bindings for Python3 as well and due to the Numpy error above I'm not sure how to proceed? It seems like it's trying to install Numpy as a dependency, which I have already.

Answer (score 0):

```
brew install opencv3 --with-contrib --with-python3 --HEAD
```

Instead of :

`brew install opencv3 --with-contrib --with-python3 --without-numpy`

and See this :

http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/05/15/resolving-macos-opencv-homebrew-install-errors/